# Char not appearing after scanf

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm making a program where you have to enter something in console and then after pressing a button on the view controller it prints that in console. When I run it the prompt gets printed but when I press the button the input doesn't get printed back. Here is my View Controller.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

char word[40];
@implementation ViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization

         NSLog(@"Please enter a word.");
    // 1
    char cstring[40];

    // 2
    scanf("%s",cstring);

    // 3
    NSString *inputString = [NSString stringWithCString:cstring encoding:1];



    }
    return self;
}

- (IBAction)changeText:(id)sender{

NSLog(@"You entered the word '%@'", inputString);

}

@end
```

Comment: What do you mean by "console"?  It may be the case (I'd have to check) that iOS does not actually set up stdin to read from the console.

Comment: @neal By console I mean the thing the arrow is pointing to in the linked picture; sorry if that isn't what it's usually called I'm not sure what the proper name for it is.[link] (http://www.cimgf.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/Screenshot-121212-1219-AM.png)

Comment: That's the lldb console and lldb is running on your mac and talking to your device over the network. You cannot mix tty console I/O like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am pretty sure that iOS doesn't set stdin for iOS applications, or if it does, it's not in a very straightforward manner (i.e. the standard C library functions for input are not likely to work).  Try reading the return value of scanf and then using NSLog() on it - you will see your log statement before any chance to enter in a string:

int ret = scanf("%s", word);
NSLog(@"%d", ret);

I am on XCode 6/iOS 8 beta4, and I see -1 as scanf()'s return value.

A better way to accomplish what you're doing is to have a TextField and read that field's value inside the action for the button push.  Also, you should be doing this in something like "viewWillAppear" or "viewDidLoad", and not initFromNib, as you're guaranteed that outlets are set up correctly by that time.